# AppleScript: Get Image Location Data

Tags: applescript, automator, gps, exif, image-processing

I am trying to write an Automator Script which involves, among other things, getting the GPS location data from an image. This will be a Finder Service.

From what I have been able to discover so far, it involves running some AppleScript and talking to the `Image Events` headless application.

From here, how do I actually get the Latitude & Longitude of the image?

I know there are applications which can read this data, including on the command line, but I wondered whether it was available to MacOS without adding anything.

Comment: I do not believe Image Events is able to get that type of meta data from the photo however `mdls` can do it, e.g. `mdls -name kMDItemLatitude -name kMDItemLongitude /path/to/photo` however it all depends what exactly your trying to do with this info. I personally prefer using `exiftool` however you'd have to install it. If you'd provide more information about what your trying to do and be a bit more explicit and specific it would be easier to write up and answer.

Comment: @user3439894 Looks Good. Can you change your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I can however do you need any additional information or are you good with just what I've said?

Comment: @user3439894 You comment answered the question I asked, so that should be enough. However, if you happen to know how to use the `-nullMarker` option (it doesn’t seem t work for me, even when I use the `raw` option), or whether there is an alternative for RAW files, that would be a bonus. Otherwise, it’s good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe Image Events is able to get that type of meta data from the photo however `mdls` can do it, e.g. `mdls -name kMDItemLatitude -name kMDItemLongitude /path/to/photo` however it all depends what exactly your trying to do with this info. I personally prefer using `exiftool` however you'd have to install it.

To answer the question in your comment:

If you query an `attributeName` when using `-raw` and the `attributeName` doesn't exist the output is literally `(null)` and if you want it to be something else then use `−nullMarker markerString`, e.g.: `−nullMarker "Does Not Exist"`

```
mdls -name kMDItemFake -raw -nullMarker "Does Not Exist" /path/to/photo
```

In the example command above `kMDItemFake` is a fake `kMDItem` item, so that command will output: `Does Not Exist` instead of `(null)`.

In other words, if as example the photo doesn't have `kMDItemLatitude` info and you query for it the output will be `(null)` when using `mdls -name kMDItemLatitude -raw`. To change that, use `−nullMarker markerString`.

If a `kMDItem` doesn't exist and you want no output when using `mdls -name attar -raw` then use `mdls -name attar -raw −nullMarker '' /path/to/photo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a related question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271289/apple-mdls-metadata-list-command-on-networked-drive for which which you might have some insight.