# Apple mdls (MetaData List) command on Networked Drive

Tags: network, command-line, metadata

I have discovered `mdls` as a way of extracting information from a (photo) file. However, I have found that it doesn’t seem to work properly if I am accessing the file over the network. Some of the meta data is missing, most notably the GPS data which is what I wanted most.

However, if I copy the file to a local drive, then the metadata is all there, and everything is fine again. This suggests that `mdls` is looking in the wrong place for some data … ?

It gets weirder depending on the network:

- If I connect using SMB I get a limited selection of metadata
- If I connect using NFS I get the message that it could not find the file at all.

How can I use successfully `mdls` on networked files?

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI, `exiftool` (which has to be installed) can pull all *metadata* from the file over the network without the need to have the network volume indexed.

That said, the most likely reason you're only getting some of the *metadata* is because indexing is most likely turned off on the network volume.

I tested this with an SMB Share to a Linux System and copied over some photos that I know contain GPS Info.

On first query I got the same results you did, a subset of the *metadata*, however upon turning indexing on using `mdutil` and letting the volume be indexed, then `mdls` returned all *metadata* including the GPS Info.

In Terminal use the following syntax, `mdutil -i on mount_point`, e.g.:

```
mdutil -i on /Volumes/Data
```

Also, you might want to read the manual page for: [`mdutil`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdutil.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried `(sudo) mdutil -i on /Volumes/photos.smb` and get the following message: `Indexing disabled.`. This is not the result I was hoping for. BTW I am aware of the excellent `exiftool`, but I wanted a more native solution.

Comment: @Manngo, I had done this under OS X 10.8.5 and it works fine. I tried this under macOS 10.12.2 and got `Indexing disabled` too. I even tried mounting to a folder in my Home Folder and also disabling SIP, nothing worked, got the same message. Searched Google and found nothing to help. If you can't enable Spotlight to index a network share, then my only suggestion is to use `exiftool` as it pulls info directly from the file, not an index.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a data point. I also checked this under MacOS 10.2 but unlike user3439894 I'm on .3 instead of .2. When I tried mdutil -i on a network smb volume (both with sudo and without) I get the response: "unexpected indexing state". mdutil -s for the same networked volume yields: "Server search enabled." In my case the difference may be that the networked share is on our MacOS 10.8 server.
I encountered this answer while trying to figure out why tags put on a file in the Finder on the networked volume by a MacOS 10.12 machine do not appear when a different Mac running MacOS 10.10. I will have to see if a file tagged on the local Mac and then moved to the MacOS 10.8 server can have its tags read by the 10.10 Mac...